# Logging to the ULS log on a WSS 3.0 server

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0

I have a scenario where I have WSS 3.0 only on a server and I would like to be able to log to the ULS log. In most cases, I have MOSS 2007 installed on the same server and can use the class/method Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.PortalLog.LogString but that is not an option in this case.

Have anyone else been able to successfully log to the ULS log on a WSS-only server? If not, do you use a logging component instead like log4net etc or how do you log? Logging to the ULS log would be strongly preferred.

TIA,
Magnus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has documented it with this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979522.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

I use log4net with the ULS LogAppender fromCodeplex:
http://splog4net.codeplex.com/

The details on that are here:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024121951/http://geekswithblogs.net/dotnetrodent/archive/2008/09/11/125079.aspx)

And the log4net is here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html

I find this to be the best solution simply because where and how I log is something that changes from client to client and log4net allows me to re-configure this really easily.